# Vue JS Intellij setup

Tags: node.js, vue.js, intellij-idea, vue-component, single-page-application

I am working on a Vue js application but am having difficulty getting it to run/debug within IntelliJ.  I am currently running it from the command line but I'm interested in getting it to debug in IntelliJ.  Not many tutorials out here on getting this set up to work.   Is there anyone that has experience in setting up this framework and IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Steps are rather straightforward and described in [blogpost](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/working-with-vue-js-in-webstorm/):

- First, install the JetBrains IDE Support Chrome extension. This will bind the browser debugger environment with IntelliJ in real-time.
- start the server with `npm serve` (can be done from a gutter in `package.json`):

[image]

- create a new **JavaScript debug** configuration, specify the URL your app is running on (usually `http://localhost:8080`) in it, put the breakpoints right in the source code, and start the debug session.

[image]

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/03/get-started-building-apps-with-vue-js-in-webstorm/ for some hints on working with Vue.js in IDEA. And https://medium.com/dailyjs/stop-painful-javascript-debug-and-embrace-intellij-with-source-map-6fe68eda8555

Answer (score 1):

You can add "Run Configuration" for any project to run in Intellij. For this, you must have a run script in package.json.

Refer below link for a screenshot. NPM Run Configuration Sample:

[image: NPM Run Configuration Sample]

Choose NPM and give like this. Once done, you are all ready for clicking the RUN button available in the toolbar to run the project